# implementing capecha in layout in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, widget, captcha

I'm using a 'contact us' form in layout page. This is `main.php` layout page :

```
<footer class="footer">
   <div class="container" style="background-color: #F5F5F5">
      <?= \frontend\mostafa\formWidget::widget(); ?>
```

and in my custom formWidget i have rendered a view file :

```
class formWidget extends \yii\base\Widget{
...
return $this->render('post',['model'=>$model])
```

and post.php is:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode', ['template' => '{label}'])->widget(Captcha::className(), [
    'template' => '<div class="col-xs-12">{image}</div><div class="col-xs-12">{input}</div>',
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'CAPTCHA Code',
        'class' => 'form-control',
    ],
]) ?>
```

My problems are:

1. Because I'm using widget for validating the form where, should I set `CaptchaAction`?
2. Why does the Captcha always show incorrect message?
3. The Captcha picture is always the same and doesn't work.

Comment: why you have the captcha in layout?

Comment: your form have any ajax validation

Comment: 1) Why have you used the captcha in the layout? If you use it in your layout, captcha will be everywhere you call the layout. I would suggest call the layout in the contact form and use captcha in the contact form and see how it goes and post your doubts if any..

Comment: @MohanPrasad  Not sure what you're saying. i mean "call the layout in the contact form and use captcha in the contact form  " part. how can i call layout in contact form?

Comment: my bad I mean view page...

Answer (score 0):

this is form section

```
 <?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
'id'                     => 'registration-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'   => true,
'enableClientValidation' => false]);
?>
<div class="col-lg-4" style="width: 50%;">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'name', ['template' => "{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"])->textInput(['placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('name')]); ?>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4" style="width: 50%;">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'email', ['template' => "{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"])->textInput(['placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('email')]); ?>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4" style="width: 100%;">
    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'subject')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255, 'id' => 'contact_form', 'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('subject')])->label(false) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'body')->textArea(['rows' => 3, 'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('body')])->label(false) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode', ['template' => '{label}'])->widget(Captcha::className(), [
'template' => '<div class="col-xs-12">{image}</div><div class="col-xs-12">{input}</div>',
'options' => ['placeholder' => 'CAPTCHA Code', 'class' => 'form-control']]) ?>
    <div class="form-group" style="float: right">
    <?= Html::submitButton( 'sending',['class' => 'btn btn-info', 'name' => 'contact-button']) ?>
    </div>
```